# how to fireRules in Drools (with infinite loop in programme )

Tags: java, drools, business-rules, drools-fusion

I have a function(MonitorLOg) that contains an infinite loop; it's necessary because I want to monitor a file and do an action when there is a modification. However, `myRules` in Drools doesn't want to start("WS is updated" don't appear). Any suggestion?

```
rule "SmartWssec"
when
PolicyUpdateWssec(changelog == true)
then
System.out.println("WS is updated");
end
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
PolicyUpdateWssec LogModSecurity = new PolicyUpdateWssec();
LogModSecurity.MonitorLog("D:\\Mod");
kSession.insert(LogModSecurity);
kSession.fireAllRules();
LogModSecurity
```

///////////////////////////

```
        while(true){
            WatchKey key;
            try {

            // wait for a key to be available

                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                return;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                // get event type
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

                // get file name
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                Path fileName = ev.context();

                System.out.println(kind.name() + ": " + fileName);

                if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY ) {
                    changelog=true;
                    setChangelog(changelog);
                    System.out.println("WS-Policy is being Update.......");
```

Comment: Could you, pls, share here your function code? It's hard to say what's going on without this.

Comment: this is my code , thanks for your help Andriy Kryvstun